# How to return a 404 HTTP status code when promise resolve to undefined in Nest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

In order to avoid boilerplate code (checking for undefined in every controller, over and over again), how can I automatically return a 404 error when the promise in `getOne` returns undefined?

```
@Controller('/customers')
export class CustomerController {
  constructor (
      @InjectRepository(Customer) private readonly repository: Repository<Customer>
  ) { }

  @Get('/:id')
  async getOne(@Param('id') id): Promise<Customer|undefined> {
      return this.repository.findOne(id)
         .then(result => {
             if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
                 throw new NotFoundException();
             }

             return result;
         });
  }
}
```

Nestjs provides an integration with TypeORM and in the example repository is a TypeORM `Repository` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write an [interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) that throws a `NotFoundException` on `undefined`:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotFoundInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> { {
    // next.handle() is an Observable of the controller's result value
    return next.handle()
      .pipe(tap(data => {
        if (data === undefined) throw new NotFoundException();
      }));
  }
}
```

Then use the interceptor in your controller. You can use it per class or method:

```
// Apply the interceptor to *all* endpoints defined in this controller
@Controller('user')
@UseInterceptors(NotFoundInterceptor)
export class UserController {
```

or

```
// Apply the interceptor only to this endpoint
@Get()
@UseInterceptors(NotFoundInterceptor)
getUser() {
  return Promise.resolve(undefined);
}
```

Comment: Thanks works very well! It would be great to define the interceptor as a factory, meaning passing arguments without the need to call `new NotFoundInterceptor()`. Do you have any idea how?

Comment: Great! :-) Have a look at `useFactory` in [custom providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers). You can inject the arguments of the factory as a provider itself. Depending on your use case, this might be what you need.